# spinnaker returned exposure time not liking an arithmetic operation

Tags: python, pyspin

I am using PySpin / python wrapper for spinnaker (Flir camera SDK).

There is a  `cam.ExposureTime.GetValue()` method to get the current exposure time of the camera. I am able to use it like this:

```
print("Exposure time set to %.2f µs." % cam.ExposureTime.GetValue())
```

This works fine and prints the exposure time in micro seconds.

Next, I wanted to display time in milliseconds so I did the following:

```
print("Exposure time set to %.2f ms." % float(cam.ExposureTime.GetValue())/1000)
```

Python doesn't like it! I get an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

A simple statement like `float('12.67')/10` runs without any problem. Not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the issue was due to an arithmetic operation on PySpin returned value inside a `print` statement. I moved the operation before `print` statement and that solved by issue.

I simply used:

```
exp_time = float(cam.ExposureTime.GetValue())/1000
print("Exposure time set to %.2f ms." % exp_time )
```